# Keras (activity) regularizer parameterized using the input data from the assigned layer

Tags: keras, regularized

Is it possible to implement an activity regularizer in Keras that is parameterized using the input data from the assigned layer?

Alternatively, is it possible to modify the loss function for a particular layer based on both the input and the output to the layer?

While it seems possible to implement a loss function for the whole network, it is unclear whether it is possible to implement and apply a loss function to a specific layer(s). Is this possible? How would I go about implementing this?